# Flutter/Android Studio: debug async function

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Hey I want to debug a Flutter `async` function in **the debugger of Android Studio**. I have a breakpoint and when I evaluate the function I get this error:

```
Cannot evaluate
```

This is caused by the fact that the function I am trying to debug is `async`:

```
await client
.lookup<PtrResourceRecord>(ResourceRecordQuery.serverPointer(name))
```

I will get the same error regardless of the actual `async` function that I am trying to debug (network request, shared preferences etc.):

[image: android studio debugger]

Restarting the app every single time is quite slow and is ridiculously annoying in debug mode.

There has to be better way than to restart the app with a different print statement everytime. How do I actually use the **debugger** in Android Studio with `async` funtions?

Comment: Ever found an answer?

Comment: @il_boga nope :/